# como enviar progreso de unas inserciones de php a js

Tags: php8

Hola estoy insertando unos archivos utilizando php pero requiero q en cada iteraccion se actualize el progreso al cliente front en js trate de utilizar el bufer de salida ob_flush pero los mensajes los devuelve al final del ciclo for y necesito q se envien uno a uno

```php
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($files['name'][0]); $i++) {
            if ($files['size'][0][$i] > 0 && $files['error'][0][$i] === 0) {
                $tempFilePath = DIRECTORIOINICIO . '/docusevenet/temp/importaciones/' . $files['name'][0][$i];
                if (move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][0][$i], $tempFilePath)) {
                    $archivo = new Archivo;
                    $java_command = $archivo->verificarConexionJava();
                    $nfpaginas = 0;
                    if (trim($java_command) != '') {
                        $command = $java_command . ' -jar '
                            . DIRECTORIOINICIO . '/docusevenet/subir_archivo/countPage.jar "'
                            . $tempFilePath . '"';
                        $cantidadPaginasExec = exec($command);
                        $cantidadPaginasArray = explode("->", $cantidadPaginasExec);
                        if (count($cantidadPaginasArray) == 3) {
                            $nfpaginas = $cantidadPaginasArray[2];
                        }
                    }
                    $valorFinalRutaEnDiscoDuro = false;
                    if (!defined('RUTADISCODURO')) {
                        $conex_fich->campos = "valor";
                        $resRDD = false;
                        $resRDD = $conex_fich->arraySql(
                            $conex_fich->consultaSql_Condi(
                                "parametro like 'RUTADISCODURO'",
                                "parametros_generales"
                            )
                        );
                        if ($resRDD) {
                            $valorFinalRutaEnDiscoDuro = $resRDD['valor'];
                            define("RUTADISCODURO", $valorFinalRutaEnDiscoDuro);
                        } else {
                            define("RUTADISCODURO", false);
                        }
                    }
                    $militime = (int) microtime(true);
                    $img_sevenet    = RUTADISCODURO; // traer desde base de datos
                    $image_route    = $img_sevenet . "/" . date("Y") . "/" . date("m") . "/" . date("d") . "/";
                    if (!file_exists($image_route)) {
                        mkdir($image_route, 0777, true);
                    }
                    $image_route   .= $militime . $militime . rand(100, 999); // nombre del archivo
                    if (@copy($tempFilePath, $image_route)) {
                        error_log(serialize($_POST));
                        $unit             = 0;  //unidad de conservacion 0 imagen
                        $folder_id         = $_POST['folder_id']; //id padre
                        $name             = $files['name'][0][$i]; //nombre archivo
                        $dependence_id  = $_POST['id_dependence']; // id dependencia
                        $length         = $files['size'][0][$i];
                        $actual_archive = $_POST['current_file']; //estado del archivo historico gestion central
                        $actual_archive_id = $_POST['current_file_id']; //iid del estado actual del archivo
                        $status         = 1; //estado con imagenes
                        $fgraba         = date("Ymd");
                        $login          = $_POST['admin'];
                        $pages          = $nfpaginas;
                        $ext            = "pdf";
                        $_SESSION['la'] = $_POST['admin'];

                        $archivo->setIdUnidadConservacion($unit);
                        $archivo->setIdPadre($folder_id);
                        $archivo->setNombre($name);
                        $archivo->setIdDependencia($dependence_id);
                        $archivo->setEstado($status);
                        $archivo->setLogin($login);
                        $archivo->setFGraba($fgraba);
                        $archivo->setImagenes($pages);
                        $archivo->setExt($ext);
                        $archivo->setLongitud($length);
                        $archivo->setRutaImagen($image_route);
                        $archivo->setArchivoActual($actual_archive);
                        $archivo->setIdArchivoActual($actual_archive_id);

                        $archivo->setIdFlujo(0);
                        $archivo->setIdDoc(0);
                        $archivo->setIdSerie(0);
                        $archivo->setFFinal($fgraba);
                        $archivo->setFInicial($fgraba);
                        $archivo->setArchivoProcedente('nulo');
                        $archivo->setTransferir('');
                        $archivo->setEncriptada('false');

                        $archivo->obtenerPermisosPadre();
                        $archivo->grabarArchivoFichero();
                        $contador++;
                        $id_file = $archivo->getIdArchivo();
                        $progreso = ($contador / count($files['name'][0])) * 100;
                        array_push($correct_id, $name);
                    }
                }
                
            }
            // Enviar una respuesta al cliente (usando Server-Sent Events)
            echo "data: " . json_encode(['status' => 'procesado', 'message' =>
            $name . ' procesado correctamente; progreso total' . $progreso . '%']) . "\n\n";
            flush();
```